# Identifying the clause elements of the following sentence

Tags: clauses

I have a problem identifying the clause elements in the following sentence:

> True phobias consist of an intense irrational fear

Is it correct to say that 'True phobias' = Subject, 'consist of' = Verb and 'an intense irrational fear' = Complement of the subject? or 'an intense irrational fear' = object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would make more sense to treat *consist of* as a *phrasal verb* functioning as a single unit.

You then have the sentence parsed as: NP+Phrasal verb+Subject complement (which describes phobias.)

Comment: Yes, to add to it, it is a single-clause sentence, rather a simple sentence.